# Spread betting on UK house prices

Tags: spreads

There are articles online which discuss spread betting on house prices. However I have been unable to find companies that offer spreads on any of the well known UK house price indices.

Given that this stackexchange isn't designed for advertising particular institutions...

How should one find reputable organisations that offer markets on UK house price indices?

What search terms should I be using? (The obvious 'spread betting uk house prices' didn't take to me anything useful.)

Comment: I just googled "spread betting on house prices" and found an article which mentions a spread betting company (IG.com)?

Comment: @RonJohn Thanks, I tried them but could not find any markets once I'd created an account.

Answer (score 1):

IG Index used to do spread bets on the Halifax House Price Index. But [they stopped](https://www.financial-spread-betting.com/Ig-index-house-spreads.html). I don’t think you’ll find another provider.

Comment: That was the best write up I had found.  What makes you say that you don't think I'll find another provider? Do people not do this any more?